# How to use a custom geojson file for plotting library maps with plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

I am very new to Python and still learning the language. I was going through Plotly library and trying to understand how to use an external geojson file to use in some of the custom maps available on their site. I am unable to understand how to use the geojson file to create the site map with data at my end.
The geojson data used in the map is called as below -

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
    counties = json.load(response)
```

The main map visual code is as shown below -

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/fips-unemp-16.csv",
                   dtype={"fips": str})

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.choropleth(df, geojson=counties, locations='fips', color='unemp',
                           color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
                           range_color=(0, 12),
                           scope="usa",
                           labels={'unemp':'unemployment rate'}
                          )
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

I need help to understand how to use a geojson file (available at my end) with the above code.

Thanks in advance.